# How do I find words that have more than two letters but do not start with a specific two letters using the glob patterns for file matching for tcsh?

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

Basically I have a list of words/folders (e.g. a cr cr1 cr22 ch dr eegh)

using

> echo ^cr*

I can filter the list and get words that do not begin with cr (e.g. a ch dr eegh)

using

> echo ??*

I can filter the list and get words with two letters or more (e.g. cr cr1 cr22 ch dr eegh)

So my question is, how can I combine both of them (command must start with echo, but grep or other commands can be used ) so I can get words that do not begin with cr and contain two or more letters?  (e.g. ch dr eegh)

Comment: What shell are you using? I'm pretty sure that `^` does not work in Bash.

Comment: The `^` excludes patterns in tcsh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you're looking for words

- starting with anything but `c`, followed by one or more characters
- starting with `c`, then one character other than `r`

Here you go:

```
echo [^c]?* c[^r]*
```

Answer (score 2):

//When this was posted, it was assumed that the OP was using bash, a reasonable assumption.

It is impossible if you only want to only use `echo`.

`echo` by itself does not search through text, it just passes its `kwargs` to `stout`. The best way to handle this would be with `grep` and by writing a regex.

Comment: Sorry, I meant echo must be included.  Can I possibly use echo and grep to accomplish it?